# vim solarized in visual mode loses syntax coloring in selection

Tags: vim, solarized

When I do a selection in visual mode with vim and colorscheme solarized, the selection loeses its syntax highlighting. Instead, it is darkgray on light grey. However, when I switch to another colorscheme and select something, the syntax-color stays. How can I get the syntax colors in the selection (idealy with the solarized light colors)?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to edit your colorscheme. Search for the Visual directive and change the guifg and ctermfg value to NONE. You'll have to be very smart with the guibg/ctermbg value, though, because it will probably clash with a bunch of foreground colors.